# get concepts of a loaded ontology using OWL API

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I try to get all 'subclass-of' axioms of an ontology. I tried by using the following statement.

```
 System.out.println(MyOntology.getAxioms(AxiomType.SUBCLASS_OF));
```

Effectively, it returns the ontology 'subclass-of' axioms, except for the first 'subclass-of' axiom which links `OWL:Thing` with my first ontology class.

I cannot understand why this link isn't taken into account in that case ?

Is there any way to get all 'subclass-of' axioms including those linking  `OWL:Thing` with other classes ?

Here you can find the ontology screenshot and the issue description:

[image]

Comment: Is that axiom asserted in the ontology? OWLAPI will only return asserted axioms.

Comment: Yes it is; please have a look at the ontology screenshot I've just added, it's more descriptive

Comment: Please add the ontology in a parsable format, to allow replication. Your code looks correct, so we need the actual data to find out what's wrong.

Comment: I found the issue:  protégé doesn't generate the subclass of axiom when adding first level ontology (sub-)classes, I didn't notice that. Once I add them manually, I mean the subclass axioms, the program can return them. Thank you, Ignazio, for your help